# Set containers' tensileLength universally

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to set a constant `tensileLength` for all my scrollable containers?

Right now, the tensileLength is too much for me as containers stretch beyond half of the screen on iOS devices.

I can change them individually but I have a lot of Scrollable containers in my hand written forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the DefaultLookAndFeel and override the bind method.
Something like this:

```
UIManager.getInstance().setLookAndFeel(new DefaultLookAndFeel(UIManager.getInstance()){
  public void bind(Component cmp) {
        if (cmp instanceof Container) {
            cmp.setTensileLength(...);
        }
    }
});
```